# Validate form text input

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm developing a registration page using Zend Framework.

Phone, Mobile, ID Number are the fields I'd like to Validate. So far I have a validation only for Not Empty.

I couldn't find the right solution so maybe you can help me out.

I want the phone and mobile fields to be only integers for ex. 12345667 and to have specific length, for ex. minimum 7 digits.

and the same thing goes with ID NUMBER field too.

This is how it looks right now:

```
$phone = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone');
$phone->setLabel('Phone')
      ->setAttribs(array('class' => 'inputtext'))       
      ->setOptions(array('size' => '50'))       
      ->setRequired(false)
      ->addFilter('StripTags')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim')
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

Comment: Trying to avoid sarcasm... did you read the manual?  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators

Comment: ficuscr - actually it might sound strange, but I couldn't and didn't find in Docs (though it's obvious it had to be there) the page that you linked here.. Thanks mate!

Comment: Actually I can believe that.  I don't think those docs are very well structured.  Glad you found what you were looking for.

Comment: You can't represent a phone number as an integer as some begin with 0, you'll have to use a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and give you some answer for your question.

If you don't already realize it the validators in Zend_Form are the same validators  used as [standard validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html) in Zend_Validate, you usually just use the class name as a *string* instead of calling *new*. The same is true for filters and Zend_Filter

The closest standard validator available for a phone number would be the ['Digits'](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.digits) validator.

```
$phone = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone');
$phone->setLabel('Phone')
      ->setAttribs(array('class' => 'inputtext'))       
      ->setOptions(array('size' => '50'))       
      ->setRequired(false)
      ->addFilter('StripTags')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim')
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
//add digits validator , closest available to phone number in standard validators;
$phone->addValidator('Digits');
```

However you may find it more appropriate to construct your own validator by extending [Zend_Validate_Abstract](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html). A phone number validator might look like:

```
//validates US phone numbers using Zend_Validator_Regex
class MyNamespace_Validator_Form_Usphone extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const PHONE = 'phone';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::PHONE => "'%value%' is not a valid U.S. phone number.
            Phone number must be entered in (xxx)xxx-xxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx format."
    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->_setValue($value);

        $isValid = true;
        $pattern = ('/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/');
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
            $this->_error(self::PHONE);
            $isValid = false;
        }
        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

and would be used in your form element:

```
$phone->addValidator(new MyNamespace_Validator_Form_Usphone());
```

***One thing to keep in mind:*** If you set a form element as `'Required'` using the `'NotEmpty'` validator is redundant in most cases as `setRequired()` calls `'NotEmpty'` internally.

Also remember that typically in Zend_Form filters are applied prior to validation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a validator like

```
 ->addValidators(
                'StringLength',
                true,
                array('min' => 7,   'max' => 20,'messages' => "ID NUMBER contain at least 7 character.")
            );
```